# Google App Engine search is not using creation date as default rank

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

In their documentation [Google says that App Engine's search api uses current timestamp as document rank by default](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#other_document_properties), but it doesn't. The following code:

```
from google.appengine.api import search

index = search.Index("my_index")

index.put([search.Document(doc_id="doc1", fields=[search.TextField(name="k",value="val")])])
index.put([search.Document(doc_id="doc2", fields=[search.TextField(name="k",value="val")])])
index.put([search.Document(doc_id="doc3", fields=[search.TextField(name="k",value="val")])])

print [r.doc_id for r in index.search("k:val")]
```

prints this: `[u'doc2', u'doc3', u'doc1']``

putting a delay of 1 second between `put` calls yields the same result.

Supplying your own document rank does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it works correctly. By default search returns its results by descending rank (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/best_practices). So, if you put a delay between inserting 'doc1' and the other inserts, the timestamp of doc1 is the smallest and hence shows up last in the result.

Here is a slightly enhanced version of your sample code. It uses two delays and prints out the doc_id along with the timestamp:

```
from google.appengine.api import search
import webapp2
import time


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    index = search.Index("my_index")

    index.put([search.Document(doc_id="doc1", fields=[search.TextField(name="k",value="val")])])
    time.sleep(1)
    index.put([search.Document(doc_id="doc2", fields=[search.TextField(name="k",value="val")])])
    time.sleep(1)
    index.put([search.Document(doc_id="doc3", fields=[search.TextField(name="k",value="val")])])

    self.response.write([r.doc_id + ", " + str(r.rank) for r in index.search("k:val")])

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  (r'/.*', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Sample output:

[u'doc3, 107916240', u'doc2, 107916239', u'doc1, 107916238']